How to convert a form to a frame?
I have a form which should have been a frame. I've tried to convert it to a frame, but it seems to stay a form no matter what I do. I've compared the DFM and PAS of a form with a frame and replaced all the uses, changed the inherited class, looked through DFM.
I can't see what is causing it to be a form. What causes a form to be a form? I want to convert it to a frame?
I don't want to create a new frame and copy/paste everything over to the frame. Surely there must be a way to simply convert a form to a frame? or frame to form?

Besides the DFM and PAS, you also have to tweak the DPR and DPROJ.

Be aware that TFrame descendants do not have several events like e.g. OnCreate, OnDestroy, OnActivate and OnShow!

To convert a VCL form to a frame you have to make these changes:

Change the ancestor from TForm to TFrame in the .pas file, eg:
type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)

change to
type
  TForm2 = class(TFrame)


In the uses part of your project's .dpr file, add a : TFrame next to your frame's name, like this:
Unit2 in 'Unit2.pas' {Form2},

change to
Unit2 in 'Unit2.pas' {Form2: TFrame},



Close and reopen Form2. The IDE complains about properties that can not be applied to a frame - click on the "Ignore" button.
That's it.
NOTE: You might want to change the class name of your converted frame if the class name gets misleading, but I consider this to be not in the scope of your original question.
NOTE: I've tested this answer on Delphi XE2.

It would be much better if you didn't call everything TForm2

@DavidHeffernan, I left the class name TForm2 on purpose - it's the default name of a form and anyone using Delphi will recognize it. If I changed it to something like TFormThatShouldBeFrame, then I would have to post more code, to keep everything consistent (like explaining where FormThatShouldBeFrame comes from in {FormThatShouldBeFrame: TFrame}). I didnt' want ending up explaining the structure of Delphi VCL forms project.

TForm1 would have made sense, as would TMyForm or TFrame1 or TMyFrame, as generic names. But the 2 is just weird. It feels sloppy to me.

I've tested the procedure of converting a form to a frame on Form2 so I present the results I can back up. Form1 would imply I'm converting the Main application form into a frame. I just don't want to face the implications of that in my response. I

Nobody calls a form TForm1 it's only ever a placeholder which is then replaced with a descriptive name.

@DavidHeffernan If you're wanting to convert a frame to a form, chances are you already have a main form, in which case the form you're converting could very well be Form2, not Form1.  And although I have no idea whether anyone else leaves them as TForm1, I know I don't, but then it's common to see such names on examples.

Hi, @DavidHeffernan, I'm Nobody (sometimes)

@HeartWare not in real world programs that are developed over a significant period of time

@DavidHeffernan, Not all programs are "real world programs that are developed over a significant period of time", and we don't know if this is one of those.  Some are commercial programs, others are hobbyist programs for nobody but the programmer, some are for testing ideas, and others are school exercises.  But I'm curious, do you rename all controls, or just some?  For me (a hobbyist), I do rename all forms, frames, and other controls that are referred to in code, but not other controls such as static labels.

@PhilipJ.Rayment I name everything without fail
